# Spring Boot 3.0.0-M5 with native-image result in runtime error: "Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server."

Tags: spring-boot, graalvm-native-image

My Spring Cloud 2022.0.0-M5 + Spring Boot 3.0.0-M5 webmvc application works as a normal JVM application but fails when compiled to native:

```
c.e.m.w.proxy.server.MyServerKt  : Starting MyServerKt using Java 17.0.4.1 on acc1dd6cfd4d with PID 1 (/workspace/myserver.MyServerKt started by cnb in /workspace)
c.e.m.w.proxy.server.MyServerKt  : The following 1 profile is active: "prod"
o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Fetching config from server at : http://configserver:8080
o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServerConfigDataLoader   : Located environment: name=application, profiles=[prod], label=null, version=4563ba0531478bdc637b677819dedcebf7bd2bc3, state=null
w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Unable to start web server
o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Web application could not be started as there was no org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.server.ServletWebServerFactory bean defined in the context.

Action:

Check your application's dependencies for a supported servlet web server.
Check the configured web application type.
```

Do you have any idea where should I start investigating?

All I see in the AOT build log that Tomcat is on the classpath:

```
    [creator]         Executing native-image -H:+StaticExecutableWithDynamicLibC --enable-url-protocols=http --initialize-at-run-time=io.netty ... -cp ... :/workspace/BOOT-INF/lib/tomcat-embed-core-10.0.23.jar: ...
```

AOT building environment info:

```
    [creator]      Version info: 'GraalVM 22.2.0 Java 17 CE'
    [creator]      Java version info: '17.0.4.1+1-LTS'
    [creator]      C compiler: gcc (linux, x86_64, 7.5.0)
```

Comment: "why you use "milestone" releases" - This is a new project in an early phase, so I'd like to avoid the migration problems in advance (Spring Boot 3 will be released soon - https://www.infoq.com/news/2022/10/spring-boot-3-jax-london/).
Besides, as I understood, Spring Boot 3 will have better built-in native support than the 2 release line: https://spring.io/blog/2022/09/26/native-support-in-spring-boot-3-0-0-m5